# how to know if I reached max accuracy with window.navigator.watchPosition()

Tags: html, geolocation, mobile-website

I'm developing a mobile web application where I propose a button to show the (immobile) user his current position on the map. Since GPS fixing can be long, I decided to use watchPosition() and update the map with a marker and an accuracy circle around it so that users knows something is happening.

Now I'd like to remove the circle and stop the watch when max accuracy is achieved, but I don't know how to do that, the iPhone and google chrome desktop never give 0 meters accuracy.

Did GPS application developers settle on a "good enough" accuracy (like 150m is enough for everybody, or something of the like) ?